# Can the "Fluent" UI ribbon controls co-exist with the new "Microsoft Ribbon for WPF"?

Tags: wpf-controls, ribbon, ribbon-control, fluent-ribbon

We have an app in progress/development using the Office Fluent UI ribbon control library. It seems that the new RTM release of the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF is going to be the standard for the Microsoft libraries (at least for the next month or so).

Can we install the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF safely on our dev boxes and begin transitioning our WPF xaml to the new control structure while still supporting/running versions of the older Fluent controls?

Can they be referenced in the same project so that we can re-code one window at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The can co-exist on your machine, but they are in the same namespace, so you cannot reference them both in the same project (at least not easily).

The XAML schema is different as well. It's much improved, but you'll have to do a lot of rework of your existing XAML if you've been using the Fluent UI versions.